# Using parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar" brings the Dark ActionBar

Tags: android, themes, android-actionbar

This is my current style file, as I want to have a dark theme with a light ActionBar.

```
<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="@android:Theme.Holo">
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
</style>

<style name="MyActionBar" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:background">#FF00FF</item>
</style>
```

That works correctly, as my ActionBar as a pink background (not shared in screenshot because it would be too confusing).

But, unfortunately, despite the fact that I used: Widget.Holo.**Light**.ActionBar, my ActionBar is still dark themed:

[image]

How would it be possible to force a Light ActionBar on my dark theme?

Comment: Where is the pink background?

Comment: Not in this screenshot. But it works, the screenshot would be confusing with the pink bg

Comment: Are you referring to that drop down(and this would apply to other parts as well)? If the answer is yes wouldn't it make sense to also override the `actionDropDownStyle`(and other attributes) style from `Theme.Holo` to point to the Light version(as the `android:actionBarStyle` only changes the background, text attributes of the actual `ActionBar` etc)?

Comment: I think that's indeed what I will do. I was hoping a single line addition to style.xml, but I will go through all these modifications.

Comment: Yeap, if you want the complete `Light` look then you'll need to override all the `Actionbar` style attributes.

Comment: Have you tried it and if yes: with success, @Waza_Be ?

Answer (score 0):

This might be helpful for you:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light">
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/AppTheme.ActionBar</item>
    <item name="android:textAllCaps">false</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.ActionBar" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/actionbar_background</item>
    <item name="android:titleTextStyle">@style/AppTheme.ActionBar.Text</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/white</item>
</style>
```

In `<item name="android:background">@drawable/actionbar_background</item>` you can declare the drawable xml if you want the gradients or you can directly declare the color value here.

Comment: You can try your code with style name="AppTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo and it won't work anymore ;-). My requirement is to use a Holo non Light for everything except for the ActionBar